# SQL Select Users Who age is 17 between Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Select Users Who were 17 During a range of dates (From and End Date)--

Thanks everyone!

**Users**

- id
- birthdate

**Example:**

1. User_1 Birthdate **09/28/1996**
2. User_2 Birthdate **08/25/1996**
3. User_3 Birthdate **07/28/1995**
4. User_4 Birthdate **05/25/1995**

If Range of dates are **FROM 03/05/2013** To **End Date 6/05/2013**
*User_1 and User_2 Appear because they meet the criteria of being 17 during that time period*

**HOWEVER**

If Range is **From 02/10/2012** and **To End Date 06/05/2013**
*All the Users should appear since they all were 17 at some point during the range of date*

I have tried using the Datepart() but i can't clearly think it through to derive at the answer I want

```
Select u.id, u.birthdate
From Users u
where convert(varchar,DATEPART(MM,u.birthdate))<=DATEPART(MM,'03/05/2013')
```

With everyone help I came to a conclusion

```
DATEADD(YY,17,birthdate) between @from and @end
```

Comment: You could try to calculate when 17th birthday took place, like in `DATEADD(YEAR, +17, BirthDate)`.

Comment: btw, `User_1` just made 17 years on `2013-09-28` (1996+17), so it won't show up between 2013-03-05 and 2013-06-05

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These should do it;

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE birthdate BETWEEN DATEADD(year, -18, '2013-03-05')   -- lo date of range
                    AND DATEADD(year, -17, '2013-06-05');  -- hi date of range

SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE birthdate BETWEEN DATEADD(year, -18, '2012-02-10')   -- lo date of range
                    AND DATEADD(year, -17, '2013-06-05');  -- hi date of range
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5e8d/2).

Note that User_1 turns 17 on 09/28/2013 and User_2 on 08/25/2013, so neither of them is (or should be) included in either range.

Comment: +1 . . . This is the best solution.  Doing the date arithmetic on the date constant is better than doing the arithmetic on the column `birthdate` -- because an index on `birthdate` could be used for the query.

Comment: Thanks.. I just came to that conclusion. i have DateAdd(YY,17,birthdadte) between from and end

Comment: I believe `between` would include users on their 18th birthday. I've updated my answer to explain this potentially incorrect result.

Answer (score 2):

**My Preferred Method:**

Use date datatypes and explicit comparisons between dates.  I recommend storing birthdate as a date datatype in SQL Server 2008+, and also using [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for datetime literals to avoid ambiguity.

```
select id, birthdate
from Users
where birthdate > dateadd(year, -18, '2013-03-05') -- Check lower bounds
    and birthdate <= dateadd(year, -17, '2013-06-05'); -- Check upper bounds
```

Note that I've moved the `dateadd` function to the constants for this revision.  As keenly observed by others, this means less calculation (unless you only had 1 row?), and -- perhaps more importantly -- allows for usage of an index on birthdate.

**The `BETWEEN` Method:**

As shown in another answer, using `BETWEEN` can yield a similar result:

```
select id, birthdate
from users 
where birthdate between dateadd(year, -18, '2013-03-05')
        and dateadd(year, -17, '2013-06-05')
```

However, `BETWEEN` is inclusive, meaning it will match on all of the range *including* the end points.  In this case, **we would get a match on any user's 18th birthday**, which is most likely not the desired result (there is often an [important difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(law)) between ages 17 and 18).  I suppose you could use an additional `DATEADD` to subtract a day, but I like to be consistent in my my usage of `BETWEEN` as [Aaron Bertrand suggests](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).

**What Not To Do:**

Do not use `DATEPART` or `DATEDIFF` for this type of comparison.  They do not represent timespans.  `DATEDIFF` shows the difference in terms of *boundaries crossed*.  See how the following age of just one day would show someone as being a year old already, because the years are technically one apart:

```
select datediff(year, '2012-12-31', '2013-01-01'); -- Returns 1!
```

A calculation using 'DATEPART' for years in this fashion would yield the same thing (similarly with months/12, etc., all the way to milliseconds).

Thanks to all who noted the indexing possibility.  Let's just not forget the sequence of ["Make it work, make it right, make it fast."](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast)

Comment: If you switch the DATEADD to the 2013-03-15/2013-06-05 part, you could even make use of an index on birthdate if there is one I think?

Comment: @Kevin, absolutely. I've updated my answer to reflect this and other thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM
Users
WHERE
        DATEDIFF(year,@DATE1, '02/10/2012') = 17
OR
    DATEDIFF(year,@DATE2, '06/05/2013') =17
```

Replacing @DATE1 and @DATE2 above with the required dates.

Comment: there is a problem . it is only showing  users who are 17 at those 2 dates. what about users who were 17 in between

Comment: Exactly, do not use DATEDIFF for this.